# how do you convert your aps_developer_identity.cer to a .p12 to use with windows

Tags: iphone, windows, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to convert my apns cert to p12 so i can use it with .net

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate